# Angular2 Jasmine test case Can't resolve all parameters for NavBarComponent: (?, ?)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm working on Angular2 Angular CLI project and I'm writing Jasmine test cases for components, components of my project dependent on services (They are params to component constructors). When I try to write tests for components, I get **Can't resolve all parameters for NavBarComponent: (?, ?)**.

I have mocked services and was able to write tests for services. However, I'm getting above issue when for component test cases.

It will be great to know how to fix this issue.

Here is my code

```
export class NavBarComponent implements OnInit {
      constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,private service:       AppService){

        }
}
```

Spec file

```
describe('NavBarComponent component ', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [FormsModule, HttpModule],
            declarations: [NavBarComponent],
            providers: [{ provide: Router, useClass: class { navigate = jasmine.createSpy('navigate'); }}, 
            {provide: AppService, useClass: AppService},
            {provide: DomSanitizer, useClass: DomSanitizer}],
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
        });
    });


     it('check the number of li elements in NavBarComponent component',
        async(() => {
            TestBed
                .compileComponents()
                .then(() => {
                    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavBarComponent);
                    let userDOMEl = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
                    expect(userDOMEl.querySelectorAll('li').length).toEqual(17);
                });
        }));


});
```

Comment: add your constructor and test you tried. Always add meaningFul required code when you ask question

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when my `tsconfig.json` had the compiler option `emitDecoratorMetadata` set to `false`, and switching to `true` resolved it.